# Is there a way to disable focus on a label element that has a for attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for my forms validation.
Currently, the way it works is that after clicking submit the validation errors appear in front of the fields. When I click on those error messages, the field comes into focus. I want to disable that focus because it is causing problems in my file uploading field as it opens up the uploader.

I have tried using `focusInvalid: false` but I am unable to achieve my required functionality. The input fields have ids and the error messages are labels which use "for" attribute for the binding with the field.

```
<input type="text" id="field"/>

<label id="field-error" for="field">Field is Required</label>
```

I want to disable the focus in of the fields when the error is clicked on.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. Thank you so so much <3

Comment: No prob :) I'll put it as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('#field-error').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

or in ECMAScript 6

```
$('#field-error').click(e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Just as a side note, I would also advise applying some kind of class to each of the error label elements, such as `.errorField` you could still use your ID's if you wanted, like `<label id="field-error" class="errorField" for="field">`, it would just make applying the above to all of the elements much easier, as below:

```
$('.errorField').click(e=>{ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: Why are you providing the answer with ECMA6 when the question was not asking about this?   [Except for this answer, 100% of the questions tagged with jQuery Validate contain zero ECMA6 code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+ECMA6).

Comment: Im just being helpful @Sparky